# Strings intersection

Tags: javascript, string, search, intersection

I have three variables with string values. Need to find the longest intersection between all three lines. Like so:

```
let str1 = 'abc123efg';
let str2 = 'c123efg';
let str3 = 'abcdefg';

// result -> 'efg'
```

Yet to solve the problem is obtained by using 4 ***for*** cycles. In short, I take the string, cut into pieces of different lengths and compare them with every other string. I don't think this is the right approach.

Please advise some books or articles on the subject.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Applying a longest common substring algorithm designed to handle multiple sequences should let you to find it.

For your specific case look for "MLCS algorithm" online but...

> The multiple longest common subsequence problem (MLCS) is to find the
>   longest subsequence shared between two or more strings. It is an
>   NP-hard problem [35], with important applications in many fields, such
>   as information retrieval and computational biology [3], [9], [42],
>   [44]. For over 30 years, significant efforts have been made to find
>   efficient algorithms for the MLCS problem. Many of them, however,
>   address either the simplest case of MLCS of two strings, also known as
>   the longest common subsequence (LCS) problem [24], [36], [39], [45],
>   or the problem's special case of three strings [21], [22]. Although
>   several methods have been proposed for the general case of any given
>   number of strings [11], [22], [27], [29], they could benefit greatly
>   from improving their computation times. A method that solves the
>   general MLCS problem efficiently can be applied to many computational
>   biology and computational genomics problems that deal with biological
>   sequences [8], [28], [29], [43]. With the increasing volume of
>   biological data and prevalent usage of computational sequence analysis
>   tools, we expect that the general MLCS algorithm will have a
>   significant impact on computational biology methods and their
>   applications.

http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/5530316/

Comment: what if there are two at the same time?

Comment: what do you mean with "there are two at the same time"?

Comment: for example if you have `'123abxxx23abc'` and `'123abyyyy23abc'`, then you have two strings common `['123ab', '23abc']`.

Comment: you are perfectly right... i'll edit my answer. ty Nina